# Sticky form in select tag

Tags: php, html, html-select, sticky

I have problem with sticky forms with the select options. this is the code that my book is saying :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo ' thanks! ';
    $submit = $_POST['year'];
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
$y = range(1920, 1950);
echo '<select name="year">';
for ($y = 2008; $y <= 2018; $y++) {
echo "<option value=\"$y\";
if ($year == $y) {
echo ' selected="selected"';
}
echo ">$y</option>\n";
}
echo '</select>';
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUbmit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: actually there's no error with that code, but when I select an option and submit, it didn't get sticky. :(

Comment: Uh, your `$y` range is between 1920 and 1950, but your `for` loop iterates from 2008 to 2018...

Answer (score 1):

Hey you have made couple of mistakes in the code:
You should change the following code

$submit = $_POST['year']; => $year = $_POST['year'];
 and you forgot to close the string in this line:
 echo " echo "

The working code is

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
   echo ' thanks! ';
   $year = $_POST['year'];
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<?php
   $y = range(1920, 1950);
   echo '<select name="year">';
   for ($y = 2008; $y <= 2018; $y++) {
     echo "<option value=\"$y\"";
     if ($year == $y) {
       echo ' selected="selected"';
     }
     echo ">$y</option>\n";
   }
   echo '</select>';
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUbmit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

your form's target is missing. look at here :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

the "action" attribute defines the next page which your form data is going to be processed.

Edit : for stickiness; you should do the selects like this

```
for($i=1;$i<10;$i++){
  echo "<option value='".$i."' ".(($_POST["i"]==$i)?"selected":"").">".$i."</option>";
}
```

Comment: form action when leave blank it will direct you to the same page you were working on,

Comment: echo "<option value=\"$y\"; has no end quote. As the colors say up there.

Comment: yes sir, I've already fix that error as said by valentinas, but still id didn't get sticky. :(

Comment: you didnt set $year, you set $submit.

Comment: thanks for all your help! It's all clear now to me! thanks tpaksu, valentinas and of course jems. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close the string on line 13: Also you set the year to variable "$submit" but then are checking the variable "$year". These two should have the same name:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo ' thanks! ';
    $year = $_POST['year'];
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
$y = range(1920, 1950);
echo '<select name="year">';
for ($y = 2008; $y <= 2018; $y++) {
echo "<option value=\"$y\"";
if ($year == $y) {
echo ' selected="selected"';
}
echo ">$y</option>\n";
}
echo '</select>';
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUbmit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: it's just a sample code, just to demonstrate. But of course thanks for your answer, but still it didn't work.